# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements error

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I just generated new cert/profile (old ones expired) but now I cannot upload the app file using - Application Loader

I get the following error. What could be wrong? I am using RubyMotion.

ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'aps-environment' in 'Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp'."

Comment: I have very similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569882/invalid-code-signing-entitlements-errors-when-loading-build-to-itunes-connect Did you found any solution yet?