# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements errors when loading build to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, application-loader

My iOS app has a **keyboard** and an **app group** for communication.

When I try to upload build using **Application Loader**, I get the following errors:

> ERROR ITMS-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: 'MYTEAM.iphone.MAINAPP' for the key 'application-identifier' in 'Payload/MAINAPP.app/PlugIns/Keyboard.appex/Keyboard'"
>
> ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'aps-environment' in 'Payload/MAINAPP.app/PlugIns/Keyboard.appex/Keyboard'."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'MYTEAM.iphone.MAINAPP' for key 'application-identifier' in 'Payload/MAINAPP.app/PlugIns/Keyboard.appex/Keyboard' is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier."

So, obviously, *application-identifier* of compiled keyboard is wrong, and also it contains key *aps-environment* which is redundant. I don't understand why. I triple checked all identifiers in Xcode, provision profiles and app ids in **membercenter**. Everything is ok. I also deleted all derived data, caches, restarted Xcode several times but it didn't help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515349/invalid-code-signing-entitlements-error-upon-itunes-connect-validation-for-ios-a

Comment: @UmaMadhavi, I've seen it, no help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was creating an .ipa file from archive with help of command line:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $’MyAppArchive.xcarchive’ -exportPath $”MyApp” -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile Provisioning_Profile_Name
```

With only one provisioning profile specified. **That was the problem.**

Problem could be solved if one specify both profiles for app and for keyboard ([stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973011/xcodebuild-different-provisioning-profile-for-target-dependency)). Or you can simply create .ipa using Xcode, as I did.

Answer (score 5):

Cleaning project and deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, then rebuilding did the trick for me.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well. It's always the simple things. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed my issue, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This might cause because in Build setting "Code Signing" Release mode was set Developer this should be Distribution.
[image]

Comment: I don't know about you but for me `iOS Distribution` on the release never works for me. The only way I get successful is to have `iOS Developer` on all 4 fields.

Answer (score -1):

What you can try is 

1- CLEAN the Project, Delete all custom precompiled Frameworks you are using, and the Make the Build. Hope it will solve your problem.

[image]

2- Add application-identifier specifying the correct application bundle ID inside Entitlements.plist. Then include the plist in the Build Options > iOS Bundle Signing

Comment: I've already seen this. You just copypasted your answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/29033842/3050403 I've tried to delete and add all frameworks, but It didn't help to me.

Comment: Did you try to create new certificates and Prov Profile for your project with different bundle identifier ?

Comment: Yes, I did it twice.

Comment: i did as pointed here and it worked for me. the generated cordova project fails to upload times to times.